# Request value with JavaScript and show it on php file

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I want to make something like this in order to deliver a JSON:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:application/json");
require "data.php";

if(!empty($_GET['name']))
{
    $name=$_GET['name'];
    $price =$_GET['value'];

    if(empty($price))
    {
        response(200,"Product Not Found",NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        response(200,"Product Found",$price);
    }

}
else
{
    response(400,"Invalid Request",NULL);
}

function response($status,$status_message,$data)
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 ".$status_message);

    $response['status']=$status;
    $response['status_message']=$status_message;
    $response['data']=$data;

    $json_response = json_encode($response);
    echo $json_response;
}
```

The "value" on the data.php file is found by a JavaScript like this:

```
<script src='/web3.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://example.com'));
        var value = web3.xxx.getValue('xxxx');   
</script>
```

But I don't know how to pass it from the JavaScript variable to the $price variable in this php file... could you help me?

Comment: [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew suggests in his comment, you can use Ajax to get the data from your PHP-Script:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> <!-- add jQuery for easy AJAX functions -->
<script src='/web3.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://example.com'));
        var value = web3.xxx.getValue('xxxx');
        $.get("/path/to/file.php?name=&value="+value, funtion(data) { // get data from PHP-Script 
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            if (data.status_message === "Product Found") // if a product was found, set "price" to the price
                var price = data.data
        });
</script>
```

Comment: The price should be set in the first document, not in the data.php file... I think you are just creating a new variable in the javascript of the data.php. What i want is the variable "$price" defined in the first php file (call it index.php) to be replaced with the "var value" created in the javascript of the second file.

Comment: Yes, That's what I am doing in my code, I take the `value` Variable from your JS Code and pass it to the PHP File using a Get request. The PHP file will always return `{"status":200, "status_message":"Product Found", "data":PRICE}`

Comment: I'm getting this error on the console: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Luca did you try your code and did it work for you? I keep trying but there's no way to make it work.

Comment: Maybe try it w/o the `data = JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: Now, when php calls the require "data.php", it loads the entire source code of "data.php" instead of executing the script... what am I doing wrong? could we talk in a more direct way? this is so frustrating...